# Using Vlookup in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I added the loop for the cells and worksheets but I get a syntax error.

```
Sub check() 
Dim ws As Worksheet 
Dim i As Long 
For Each ws In Worksheets 

For i = 5 To 10

ws.Range("F" & i).Formula = _
 "=VLookup((CONCATENATE(C1,"" "",C5)),'C:\Documents[TestData.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$G$28,7, FALSE)"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F5").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F5").Value

Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub check()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F5").Formula = _
    "=VLookup((CONCATENATE(C1,"" "",C5)),'C:\Documents[TestData.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$G$28,7, FALSE)"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F5").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F5").Value
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

To put it in a loop you have to store the row in a variable and then use it. For example

`Range("F5")` can also be written as `Range("F" & "5")`

So now all you have to do is keep on replacing `5` in a loop. See the below example

```
Sub check()
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> From Row 5 to row 10
    '~~> Chnage as applicable
    For i = 5 To 10
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & i).Formula = _
        "=VLookup((CONCATENATE(C1,"" "",C" & i & _
        ")),'C:\Documents[TestData.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$G$28,7, FALSE)"

        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & i).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & i).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you copy it correctly? Note the underscore after "=". I just tested it again and it works...

Comment: It worked with the "_".Thanks. How can I do it so that the formula does not show up when I click on the cell.

Comment: it worked thanks. I want to do a loop, so that it also updates cells F6, F7....F10 and the the Concatenate will also change, for when its F6 then concatentate(C1,"" "",C6))

Comment: Yes you can put the above code in a loop as well. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to do a loop, so that it also updates cells F6, F7....F10 and the the Concatenate will also change, for example when its F6 then concatentate(C1,"" "",C6)). C1 doesn't change.

Comment: That is not the code that I gave. See the FOLLOWUP Section once again ;) You are also missing a `Next`